# How can I join five collision planes into a single concave box mesh?

Tags: modeling, physics, geometry

I'm trying to make a custom collision mesh to wrap a concave static mesh in Unreal 4, but I found that once I join all the individual planes making up the 'wrapping' they form an invisible closure over the concavity and make the resultant mesh convex.  This can be reproduced with a simple 5 plane open box mesh (example linked below) -- when I place a sphere above the box, enable collision and rigid body physics on everything, and press Blender timeline's play button the sphere drops into the box as expected as long as the planes are left unjoined.  When I join the planes into a single mesh, however, the box develops an invisible 'top' plane that stops the sphere.  As far as I can tell, Unreal requires a collision mesh to be a single mesh, so leaving the planes unjoined is not an option.

Why does the join operation add an invisible plane to make the complete mesh convex?  Is there any way to override this behavior and preserve the concavity in a single mesh?

Blender Version: 2.93.0

[image]

Comment: The Blender Physics simulation properties can't be exported so it doesn't affect anything in Unreal. You have to adjust something in Unreal, or may be you should try to add thickness to the mesh with the Solidify modifier.

Comment: Adding thickness with Solidify to each plane didn't make a difference.  Re: simulation export, my concern is that Blender is adding invisible geometry with the join operation and that this is being propagated to UE4 (which shows the same invisible top collider behavior as Blender's simulation)